# How to loop trough subquery and fill fields in array Json object

Tags: apex, json, sobject, loop, serialization

I have created a custom object to create a json string. I kan loop trough the list to fill in the first level/parent fields. How do I loop trough the subquery and fill the arrays in the json object.

```
  SprResult =  [SELECT id,name, Productcode__c,
                  (select id from Sales_Product_Sections__r)
                                        FROM Sales_Product__c 
                                        WHERE Productcode__c  = :ProductCode ];
        system.debug(SpJsonList);
        for(Sales_Product__c sp : SprResult){
        SalesProductJSON spJson = new SalesProductJSON();   
        SpJson.ProductCode = sp.Productcode__c;
        SpJson.ProductName = sp.Name; 
            for(Sales_Product_Section__c Sps: sp.Sales_Product_Sections__r){
                spJson.

            }
        SpJsonList.add(spJson);     
        }
```

Json object

```
public class SalesProductJSON{
    public String ProductCode;  //Productcode
    public String ProductName;  //Name
    public cls_SalesProductSections[] SalesProductSections;
    class cls_SalesProductSections {
        public String SectionCode;  //MAIN
        public String SectionName;  //Main
        public cls_SalesProductItems[] SalesProductItems;
    }
    class cls_SalesProductItems {
        public String ItemCode; //Itemcode
        public String ItemName; //Itemname
    }
    public static List<salesProductJSON> parse(String json){
        return (List<salesProductJSON>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<salesProductJSON>.class);  
    }
}
```

How would I fill for example Sectioncode or Itemcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can only query one level "down" in the child hierarchy, so you'll need a second query:

```
Map<Id, Sales_Product_Section__c> productSections = new Map<Id, Sales_Product_Section__c>([
  SELECT (SELECT ... FROM Sales_Product_Items__r) ... FROM Sales_Product_Section__c WHERE Sales_Product__c = :sprResult
]);
```

You'd create a List and populate it:

```
for(Sales_Product__c sp : SprResult){
    SalesProductJSON spJson = new SalesProductJSON();   
    SpJson.ProductCode = sp.Productcode__c;
    SpJson.ProductName = sp.Name; 
    SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductSections[] sections = new SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductSections[0];
    for(Sales_Product_Section__c Sps: sp.Sales_Product_Sections__r){
        SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductSections section = new SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductSections();
        // set data //
        Sales_Product_Section__c subItems = productSections.get(sps.Id);
        SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductItems items = new SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductItems();
        for(Sales_Product_Item__c recordItem: subItems.Sales_Product_Items__r) {
            SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductItems item = new SalesProductJSON.cls_SalesProductItems();
            // set more data //
            // then //
            items.add(item);
        }
        section.salesProductItems = items;
        // then //
        sections.add(section);
    }
    SpJsonList.add(spJson);     
}
```

I've probably made some mistakes here, but hopefully this should help you with your project.